# kustomize namespace label patching removes existing labels

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

My Kustomize patching works to label the namespace but it overrides existing labels

Here's all the manifests -

kustomize.yaml

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/vlbetal
kind: Kustomization

resources:
 - ../../../../base/labels

patches:
 - path: patches/test-patch.yaml 
   target:
     kind: Namespace 
     name: dev-test
```

test-patch.yaml

```
- op: add
  path: /metadata/labels 
  value:
    env: dev
    db: dev
```

namespace.yaml

```
api Version: v1 
kind: Namespace 
metadata:
  name: dev-test
```

How do I avoid overriding existing namespace labels ?

Comment: is there a specific reason why you are not using [`commonLabels` (`kubernetes.io`)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/#kustomize-feature-list)?

Comment: I am going to have multiple patch files in kustomize to apply labels to a bunch of namespaces and all of them will have different sets of labels. So commonlabels in kustomize will not work for my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current patch replaces the `labels` object with the given value, thus overriding all previous labels.

On a technical level, we want to add the two fields `env` and `db` to the `label`-object. Thus, we need two separate `add` operations to add the two fields:

```
- op: add
  path: /metadata/labels/env
  value: dev
- op: add
  path: /metadata/labels/db
  value: dev
```

Note that in order for this solution to work, the namespace needs to have a `labels` object already. If it does not, `kustomize` will report the following error:

```
Error: add operation does not apply: doc is missing path: "/metadata/labels/env": missing value
```

We can add an empty `labels`-section like this:

```
api Version: v1 
kind: Namespace 
metadata:
  name: dev-test
  labels: {}
```

If the namespace already has labels, e.g.:

```
api Version: v1 
kind: Namespace 
metadata:
  name: dev-test
  labels:
    foo: bar
```

Then we need to do nothing; the new labels will be added.

Comment: It did work on the first go but now I am trying with different labels, and it's complaining about the doc is missing the path "/metadata/labels/app".
Do I need to update kustomize too to work with this ?

Comment: The description is vague. I would need a reproducer to analyze the problem. --- Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: Thanks I will create new post.

Comment: This might be caused by the `labels`-section missing entirely. This can be prevented by adding `labels: {}` to the `metadata`-section of `namespace.yml`. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.
It works as expected.